# Values becoming NULL when sent to WCF API

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am fully out of ideas at this point. So I am going to be specific as possible for you.

This is the XML payload being sent over.

```
string payloadMessage = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetModifiedCases xmlns=""http://aiINDEX.com/Integration/v8"">
            <IncludeCompletedCases>true</IncludeCompletedCases>
            <ModifiedSince>2018-03-21T00:00:00-04:00</ModifiedSince>
            <IncludeChangesBesidesCaseAndDocket>true</IncludeChangesBesidesCaseAndDocket>
        </GetModifiedCases>
    </soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>";
```

This is the call using the WebClient object:

```
 wc = new WebClient();
 wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;  
 wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
 string action = "GetModifiedCases"; // Method
 string soapAction = "http://aiINDEX.com/Integration/v8/" + action;
 wc.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"" + soapAction + "\"");
 string response = wc.UploadString(URL, "POST", payloadMessage);
```

All the above is my customers application code. I own the API he is trying to get to. The receiving code is simple for taking in the request.

```
public List<CaseIntegrationInformation2> GetModifiedCases(bool includeCompletedCases, DateTime modifiedSince, bool includeChangesBesidesCaseAndDocket)
```

Here is where everything goes nuts, the very first line is to write the modifiedSince param to my log file. No matter what I have tried, in his code or mine, I always read the DateTime as NULL - specifically 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.

I have found tons of information related to this, but most of it centers around a JSON issue here or there. Nothing about a .NET app talking to a .NET app and all the variables passed just become NULL.

We have a bunch of other methods that are working fine, but anything called with a DateTime as one of the receiving parameters sets all parameters to NULL.

I've been fighting this since last week, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use a webclient rather than WCF Client?   I suspect your call is missing additional header information the WCF client will automatically create for you.   Also, can you see an app like WCFStorm to make the call to see if it is working?

Comment: Looks ok, have you tryied removing the time zone? `<ModifiedSince>2018-03-21T00:00:00</ModifiedSince>`